# make a unique number id for every item I get from the api response

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash, fetch-api

So, here I'm trying to map through a response I get from an API, before I get the items from the API, I was testing it statically and I made a unique number id for every item starting from {1} and now I'm trying find a way to make some kind of for loop for every item I get to give every item a unique number id starting from {1}, how can I achieve that?

```
<div className="items">
  {this.state.items.map(i =><a href="/" id={1} onClick={this.targetValue} className={this.state.selected === "1" ? "selected" : ""}>{i.name}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use id={Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1}  count 1 to 12

Comment: I think it can't be random in my case I just want to make a for loop from 1 to 10 or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .map gives you index and you can use that for unique id. Since you want id to start from 1 you need to to index+1 because index starts from 0

```
  <div className="items">
       {this.state.items.map((i, index) => <a href="/" id={index+1} onClick={this.targetValue} className={this.state.selected === index +1? "selected" : ""}>{i.name}. </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: what if I want to compare it to this.state.selected in the className? targetValue function includes a setState that sets selected to the "id" value

Comment: I'm trying to make this.state.selected === index but it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work when I make it with triple equals like  this.state.selected === index+1 but it does work when I just make double equals like this ==

Comment: Because this.state.selected might be different type. === works only when both operands has same value and same data type . In your case index and this.state.selected both are different data types so not working.

Comment: Yes I know but I'm setting the initial state of selected as 0 and the index is of type number so that's why I'm confused

Comment: Hmmm I am thinking about the same why it’s behaving differently

Answer (score 1):

The map function actually gives you an index as a second parameter.

```
<div className="items">
  {this.state.items.map((i, idx) =><a href="/" id={idx} onClick={this.targetValue} className={this.state.selected === "1" ? "selected" : ""}>{i.name}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I want to compare it to this.state.selected in the className? targetValue function includes a setState that sets selected to the "id" value

Comment: I'm trying to make this.state.selected === idx but it doesn't work

Comment: Then you compare `className={this.state.selected === idx ? "selected" : ""}`